# Creating density map of roads for each district using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, density

I have to illustrate a map with the road density of each district.

I have the city layer which comes with the bordered districts and another layer with all the roads.

How can I create a density map where road density is displayed for each district independently (within each district's/polygon border)?

I have ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Comment: in a few words, something like the "line density" tool but that worked for each single polygon would be great!

Comment: How many districts?  And what do you want to do about roads that cross district boundaries?